# How to prevent command line args from being interpreted by R vs. only by my script?

Tags: r, docopt

I'm using the [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.R) implementation for R. My script has a command line option where the short form is `-g`. When I run my script, it seems this argument is first interpreted by R and then by my script. Therefore I get a wrist slap about not specifying a value for the GUI. Can I prevent R from trying to work with these command line args?

Example of a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(docopt))

"docopt practice script

Usage: foo.R [-g <goodies>]

Options:
     -g <goodies>, --goodies=<goodies>  Goodies
" -> doc

opts <- docopt(doc)
cat(sprintf("goodies = %s\n", opts$goodies))
```

Here's what happens when I run it:

```
Jennifers-MacBook-Pro-3:scripts jenny$ ./foo.R -g donuts
WARNING: --gui or -g without value ignored
goodies = donuts
```

If you change the short form of the option from `-g` to `-j`, the `WARNING` goes away … but I have a good reason for using the letter `g`!

Comment: If you stick to only using `--goodies <goodies>` without the short-form eaten by R you get around it.

Comment: `-G` should work, too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @krlmlr, this issue has to do with `Rscript` (in your hash bang). One workaround would be to use the functionality provided by the excellent [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) in place of `Rscript`. For example, using `#!/usr/bin/Rscript` in `foo.R`, I get the issue:

```
[nathan@nrussell R]$ ./foo.R -g donuts
WARNING: unknown gui 'donuts', using X11

goodies = donuts
```

Replacing this with `#!/usr/local/bin/r` in a new script `foo2.R`, I get a clean output:

```
[nathan@nrussell R]$ ./foo2.R -g donuts
goodies = donuts
```

It looks like you're on an OS X machine, so if you do choose to install `littler`, just be sure to note the authors' warning:

> On OS X, you may want to build it via configure --program-prefix="l"
>   to renamed it to lr as that particular OS thinks R and r are the same

Comment: I could second the suggestion for littler but maybe I am biased :)

Comment: I would love to use litter but I would need it to run on MS Windows (GIT Bash as a matter of fact): any chances/plans for that?

Answer (score 3):

The `R` and `Rscript` commands know `--args`. Compare the output of the following:

```
R -e "TRUE" --args --silent
R -e "TRUE" --silent
```

This works due to an [early exit](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/50b005f15b07b9a605d4157417f17a85d0c4ee06/src/unix/system.c#L350-L351) if `--args` is detected. However, the `--gui` warning is triggered in a separate loop [before this](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/50b005f15b07b9a605d4157417f17a85d0c4ee06/src/unix/system.c#L266-L267).

This means that

```
Rscript -e "commandArgs()" --args --gui
```

will work but give the spurious warning, and

```
Rscript -e "commandArgs()" --gui
```

gives an error right away. It looks like only `--gui` and `-g` are affected.

As a quick-and-dirty hack, one could insert something like

```
if(!strcmp(*avv, "--args")) {
    break;
}
```

at the [beginning of the GUI-check loop](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/50b005f15b07b9a605d4157417f17a85d0c4ee06/src/unix/system.c#L260). Until this is changed in R, I suspect there's no choice but to avoid the `-g` switch or live with the (otherwise harmless) warning.

Comment: Wow. We write a ton of scripts with docopt at work but had not yet run into this issue with `-g`.  That is pretty ... braindead.

Comment: I have written exactly one script with docopt but managed to stumble right into the magic `-g` case. Lucky me.

Comment: I don't really know the protocol around marking "right" answer. Technically, this is the right answer, which is that it's impossible (?). But the `use littler` answer actually gets you moving forward again...