# Off-limits arguments to Rscript

Tags: r, bash, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I have written a series of functions to allow easier 'arg-parse'-type commandline argument parsing and check in R.  I have run into the issue briefly mentioned [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Rscript-argument-processing-minor-bug-with-g-td918350.html) but still don't entirely understand whats going on.  It seems that when trying to use "-g" as a flag,

> $ Rscript test_args.R -g foo

where test_args.R is simply:

```
#minimal program for reproducing "-g" arg behaviour
args<-commandArgs(T)
print(args)
```

I get the error and output:

> WARNING: unknown gui 'foo', using X11
>
> [ 1 ] "-g"  "foo"

it interprets that as something to change the GUI prior to actually running the script test_args.R (although the printed message shows that the "-g" does actually make it to the actual R program). This isn't mentioned in the Rscript man page, or anywhere else I can find.

Is there any way around this, and if not, is there a list of any other potential off-limits argument flags?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
based of of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698581/how-to-prevent-command-line-args-from-being-interpreted-by-r-vs-only-by-my-scri) post, I tried adding either the hash-bang #!/usr/bin/Rscript, but would ideally like to avoid users having to install littler to use the #!/usr/local/bin/r option if possible...

Comment: The Rscript is basically passing things off to R. Any options that you can pass to R you can also pass to Rscript. One parameter that R accepts is `-g` to change the GUI type. (See the `R --help` page for more information). You should probably avoid using `-g` as an option for your script. (tested with R version 3.2.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit))

Comment: That does not happen to me under Windows.  Note that the message is a warning and not an error.

Comment: @MrFlick ok, I see that on the R help page.  However, the other R flags cause any effect (I've tried '-h', '--args', '-e').  Is this something unique to the '-g' case?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck noted, thank you!

Comment: Check out the answer by @klrmlr :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698581/how-to-prevent-command-line-args-from-being-interpreted-by-r-vs-only-by-my-scri